# Flot Selection to Control multiple charts

Tags: flot

I've been trying to modify the code from the flot examples (http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/zooming/) so that I can replot a number of charts depending on the selection (i.e. changing xaxis.min and xaxis.max) and keep them all correlated.

I have no idea where to begin with regards to modifying the example, any suggestions or hints would be most welcome.

Thanks

Update modified code from zoom example help still required!

```
enter code here
$(function () {
var plots = [];
var placeholders = $(".flot");

var d1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Math.PI * 2; i += 0.25)
    d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
var data = [ d1 ];

var d2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Math.PI * 2; i += 0.25)
    d2.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
var data2 = [ d2 ];

var options = {
    series: { lines: { show: true }, shadowSize: 0 },
    /*xaxis: { zoomRange: [0.1, 10], panRange: [-10, 10] },
    yaxis: { zoomRange: [0.1, 10], panRange: [-10, 10] },
    zoom: {
        interactive: true
    },
    pan: {
        interactive: true
    }*/
    selection: { mode: "x"}
};

plots.push($.plot(placeholder, data, options));
plots.push($.plot(placeholder1, data2, options));

placeholders.bind("plotselected", function (event, plot) {
    var axes = plot.getAxes();
    for(var i=0; i< plots.length; i++) {
        plots[i].getOptions().xaxes.min = axes.xaxis.from;
        plots[i].getOptions().xaxes.max = axes.xaxis.to;
        //plots[i].getOptions().yaxes[0].min = axes.yaxis.min;
        //plots[i].getOptions().yaxes[0].max = axes.yaxis.max;
        plots[i].setupGrid();
        plots[i].draw();
        plots[i].clearSelection();
    }
    });

    });
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21662288/1355117). It deals with correlating zooming on multiple flot charts, but you can easily replace the zoom behavior with selection behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've tried to modify the code but with little success :-( the code I've adapted is below any pointers would be great...

Comment: I think I've solved it :-) thanks everybody