# Chart.js　How to synchronize pan and zoom in multiple chats

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I want to synchronize pan and zoom on multiple charts.
I'm been using Chart.js with chartjs-plugin-zoom.

charjs-plugin-zoom calls an event with the onZoom callback function. So, the values ​​at both ends of the X axis are obtained in this way with the callback function.

```
onZoom: function () {
    var minVal = myChartA.getDatasetMeta(0).dataset._scale.chart.scales['x-axis-0']._table[0].time;
    var maxVal = myChartA.getDatasetMeta(0).dataset._scale.chart.scales['x-axis-0']._table[1].time;

    leftEnd = minVal;
    rightEnd = maxVal;

    updateChart();
}
```

Then update the chart with the updateChart function.

I thought that other charts should be updated with the values ​​of both ends of the X axis obtained by the updateChart function.
Call update () with Chart.helpers.each to update all charts.

```
function updateChart() {
    Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
        instance.oprions = {
            scales: [{
                xAxes: {
                    time: {
                        min: leftEnd,
                        max: rightEnd
                    }
                }
            }]
        };
        instance.update();
    });
}
```

However, the expected result was not obtained.
Zoom-PAN reflected only the chart that was operated.

I think that onZoom callback function gets both edge of X-Axis, and updates chart every frame.
Charts can only be updated with options, so Chart.helpers.each can be used to update all charts at once. If both ends of the X axis to be updated are global variables, all graphs can be referenced.

Is this method incorrect?
Is the option update method wrong? Is the update timing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I found out how to update the chart by referring to https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html.

Actually, X-axis scales rage of multiple charts has changed, but max zoomed and stopped working again.

Reason is not to update reference.
What is ?
The sample code is written as "need to update the reference" as comment.
What's mean?

Sample code calles below:

```
xScale = chart.scales['newId'];
```

"newId" is re-assigned as scales id.

But mine is min and max value of scale.
How??

[JSFillde](https://jsfiddle.net/Fairlight/h2Lx9bmw/16/#)

Answer (score 10):

I figured out how to do this. It’s not a big deal if I know.

Callback function updateChart() should be like this:

```
        function updateChart() {
            Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
                instance.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = leftEnd;
                instance.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = rightEnd;              
                instance.update();
            });
        }
```

Point is that my data is time series data so that scale  option should be use "time".

[JSFillde](https://jsfiddle.net/Fairlight/h2Lx9bmw/33/) is updated.

Comment: Nice, but how about chart.js v3.2.1? Seems that there were some incompatible changes since last JSFiddle was attached.

Comment: Found out that linear chart (v3.2.1) will work if you change code from ".xAxes[0].time.max" to ".x.max"

Comment: If you also use `resetZoom()` to reset your zoom, it won't work anymore. You'll have to use ```instance.options.scales.x.min = null; 
      instance.options.scales.x.max = null;
      instance.update();```